# jQuery - Keep JSON keys in original order

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been having a lot of trouble with keeping the keys in a JSON object in their original state after they've been parsed by jQuery's $.each(). Even with string keys they are still being sorted into numerical order. Here is the JSON before parsed by jQuery:-

```
{
    "success": "true",
    "data": [
        {
            "row_13": {
                "id": "1_",
                "name": "_",
                "email": "_",
                "subject": "_",
                "body": "_",
                "ip": "_",
                "starred": "_"
            },
            "row_11": {
                "id": "_",
                "name": "_",
                "email": "_",
                "subject": "_",
                "body": "_",
                "ip": "_",
                "starred": "_"
            },
            "row_12": {
                "id": "_",
                "name": "_",
                "email": "_",
                "subject": "_",
                "body": "_",
                "ip": "_",
                "starred": "_"
            },
            "row_10": {
                "id": "_",
                "name": "_",
                "email": "_",
                "subject": "_",
                "body": "_",
                "ip": "_",
                "starred": "_"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, once parse by jQuery, the order is as follows:-

"row_10", "row_11", "row_12", "row_13"

What on earth is causing this? It has been bugging me for at least a day now.

Comment: There's no order in JS object properties (in ES5 at least). Use an array when you want to keep an ordered list.

Comment: Or, alternatively, have a property on the object that indicates its order.

Comment: If order matters, use an array of objects and the 12th row will be at index 11.

Comment: So, when using an API, there is no way to keep the order at all?

Comment: Maybe it's time to ditch jQuery. At least in Chrome, the order is as specified: http://jsfiddle.net/cLqL5Lg2/

Comment: @FelixKling I tried with jQuery and unsurprisingly it doesn't manage to create a different order. I don't think that my closing was right (now that we have a specified order). But this question is hardly answerable. I let you decide if it should be reopened or not.

Comment: @dystroy: I actually wrote an answer to the linked question, describing the changes in ES6. I don't have a strong opinion...